# Comparing elements of a set and deleting elements based on a criterion

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a function that has two inputs.  The first input is a set of 2-element sets, and the second input is a single 2-element set.  My function complements each 2-element set with the second 2-element set and gives me the outputs.

```
LQ[ls1_, ls2_]:=Table[Complement[ls1[[i]], ls2], {i, 1, Length[ls1]}]
```

As an example,

```
LQ[{{3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {1, 5}, {4, 6}, {2, 6}}, {1, 2}]
```

returns

```
{{3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {5}, {4, 6}, {6}}
```

This is precisely what I want, but the next step I can't figure out.  I now need to delete from this set all the 2-element sets that share an element with any 1-element sets that are present.  In particular, I need the above set to become

```
{{3,4},{5},{6}}
```

I've tried many things with little/no success.  As a matter of fact, I don't even really need to know the final set, instead, I just need to know whether there are any 2-element sets remaining when the process is finished.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How large are the lists going to be? The existing answers will get slow on large list

Answer (score 4):

```
Composition[
  With[{single = Alternatives @@ Cases[#, {x_} :> x]},
       DeleteCases[#, x : {_, _} /; MemberQ[x, single]]] &
  ,
  DeleteCases[#, Alternatives @@ #2, 2] &  (*this is LQ*)
  ][{{3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {1, 5}, {4, 6}, {2, 6}}, {1, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{3, 4}, {5}, {6}}
> ```

or we can modify last function to only check if anything is left:

```
Composition[
  With[{single = Alternatives @@ Cases[#, {x_} :> x]}, 
        MemberQ[#, x : {_, _} /; FreeQ[x, single]]] &, 
  DeleteCases[#, Alternatives @@ #2, 2] &  (*this is LQ*)
][{{3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {1, 5}, {4, 6}, {2, 6}}, {1, 2}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: This seems to work with my examples.  Just one of these days, I'd like to write something that ends up looking at least a little bit like what some of you guys come up with.  Thanks!

Comment: @Trevor Come here more often and try to fight with questions people are asking. It's the best way to learn. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
ls3 = LQ[{{3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {1, 5}, {4, 6}, {2, 6}}, {1, 2}]
(* {{3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {5}, {4, 6}, {6}} *)

Join[Pick[#2, Function[{x}, FreeQ[x, Alternatives @@ Flatten[#]]] /@ #2], #] & @@
   GatherBy[Sort@ls3, Length]
(* {{3, 4}, {5}, {6}} *)
```

or

```
Join[Select[#2, Function[{x}, FreeQ[x, Alternatives @@ Flatten[#1]]]], #1] & @@ 
    GatherBy[Sort@ls3, Length]
(* {{3, 4}, {5}, {6}} *)
```

> I just need to know whether there are any 2-element sets remaining
>   when the process is finished

```
Or @@ Function[{x}, FreeQ[x, Alternatives @@ Flatten[#]]] /@ #2 & @@ 
 GatherBy[Sort@ls3, Length]
(* True *)
```

Comment: There are many commands in there that I've never used, so it would take me a while to parse it and process everything.  However, when I change up the inputs, I do get something erroneous.  In particular, if I change {1,2} to {3,5}, LQ gives
    {{4}, {4}, {6}, {1}, {4, 6}, {2, 6}}
and the end result should delete the {4,6} and {2,6} because of the singleton {6}, but those don't get deleted (at least in the first two versions.  I just saw the third version.)

Comment: @Trevor, i updated with a fix for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
f[u_, v_] := Complement[#, v] & /@ u
g[u_] := With[{d = GatherBy[u, Length@# == 1 &]},
  {a, b} = d;
  Pick[a, FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ Flatten[b]] & /@ a]~Join~b]
```

So,

```
test = {{3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {1, 5}, {4, 6}, {2, 6}};
g[f[test, {1, 2}]]
```

gives:

```
{{3, 4}, {5}, {6}}
```

or

```
cf[u_, v_] := Composition[g, f[#, v] &][u]
```

so `cf[test,{1,2}]`